# The type or namespace 'IsolatedStorage' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly or reference?)

Tags: c#, storage, isolatedstorage

I have hit a problem with isolated storage, basically I am making an app for both windows phone and windows desktop for my isolated storage in windows phone I'm using the following;

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile userStore = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var isoFileStream = new System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream("students.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, userStore))
{
    using (var isoFileReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(isoFileStream))
    {

    }
}
```

and I assumed it would be the same for windows desktop but apparently it's not, is there a different way to achieve the same thing? To avoid the error!

Comment: I just created a new WinForms application (File -> New -> Project -> Windows Forms Application) and it was there. I even tried switching to an older framework and the Client Profile and it was still recognized. According to the docs it's defined in mscorlib so it shouldn't be a reference problem.

Comment: @CraigW hmm I'm not sure then because that's the problem that comes up. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The only thought I had was a version of the framework that doesn't support it, but I went all the way back to 2.0 and it compiled just fine every time. I even pared my references down to System, System.Drawing, and System.Windows.Forms and it still compiled. My suggestion would be to try creating a branch new project and just put that first line of code into it. If that works for you then there's some configuration problem with the original project and you'll need to do some trial-and-error to figure out what it is.

Comment: @CraigW The way I'm making the app is (File -> New -> Project -> Blank App) I just tried it again and it still doesn't work

Comment: Odd, I don't have an option for "Blank App" in the New Project dialog. Sorry, I'm afraid I'm not going to be of much help as my environment is obviously very different than yours.

Comment: @CraigW no worries mate I've figured it out, the person who answered below has said that there is no isolated storage for win store apps. I've found another way around it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be doing a .NET app for **Windows Store** (Windows 8 and above) and not a normal Win Forms App. You need to use the `Windows.Storage` namespace.

There is no direct System.IO.IsolatedStorage namespace..

use `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalData` instead of `System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile` class.

Comment: I'm already using both Windows.Storage and Windows.Storage.Pickers

Comment: The msdn confirms [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx) what @raja said: `Isolated storage is not available for Windows Store apps. Instead, use the application data classes in the Windows.Storage namespaces included in the Windows Runtime API to store local data and files. For more information, see Application data in the Windows Dev Center.`